# list custom fields from different custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I have two different custom post types: "Movies" and "Press" with different custom fields.
Now I want to display both custom fields in the single.php.

home.php:

```
...
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $query );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :  $loop->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="movie_cover">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('cover'); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>" /></a>
     </div>
...
```

single.php:

```
get_header(); ?>
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'single', 'film' ); ?>

 <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single-film.php:

```
...
<img src="<?php the_field('cover'); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>" />
...
```

the field 'cover' is from "Movies", but now i want to list the field 'release' from "Press".
Does I need a second loop?

Comment: Are you trying to get the press releases for each movie? This can be a little complicated, because you need to relate movies to press. You can have a movie_id custom field on press releases and then query it. Either way you'll need two loops one for movie and one for it's releases

Comment: yes, for each movie. but now I have another idea: I use only 1 custom post type "Movies" and insert there the 'release' field. What i want to do is: under all the films there should be 2 links: "film info" and "press". The "film info" shows title, director, etc. The "press" show all these infos too, but in addition a few more custom fields.

Comment: so i can use get_permalink for "Movies" and for the second link how do i make this? get_permalink(press) ?

Comment: i think your first idea 2 post types is better, cleaner, but it's a bit more work. I am writing up a solution right now

Comment: do you want the reviews to be shown on the single-film.php?

Comment: yes. but in addition i need a second link 'press" which show all the custom fields from both post types

Answer (score 0):

if you add movie_id custom field to press, and set it to the ID of the movie
then you can do something like inside single-film.php

```
query_posts('meta_key=movie_id&meta_value=' . get_the_ID());
```

and do another loop for the reviews

```
while have_posts() ...
```

There's a lot of additional stuff but this should get you going in the 
right direction.

I'd consider using get_posts instead of query_posts to not override wordpress' main query loop, but then you'd have to do your own manual loop:

```
 $posts = get_posts('meta_key=movie_id&meta_value=' . get_the_ID());

foreach ($posts as $p) {
echo $p->post_title; 
...
}
```

Comment: first thanks for your fast answers :)
I have still problems with this. so what i want to do is this:
I have a list of films, e.g. "Avatar". Under this film i want 2 links:
- "Movie Info" which retrieves all the infos from the custom post type "Movies". This works with get_permalink.
- "Press". This should show all the infos from "Movies", but in addition all the fields from the custom post type "Press".

Comment: you can create a page template that pulls all the info out on it, you can use get_permalink of this page instead the post. you can use shortcodes to display the info. This would be best with a plugin, when i have a moment I'll try to put something like this together for you.

Comment: thanks piotr. For the second link I figured it out. I have put a loop inside my loop